# PowerShell Parameter 'ValueFromPipeline' not working

Tags: powershell, parameters

I wrote a function to create HTML files and I'm now in the process to improve it a bit. When feeding the function through the pipeline it works fine but it's not resulting in the desired action.

This is ok:

```
Create-FileHTML -Path "L:\" -FileName "Title" "Text1", "Text2"
 L:\ Title Text1 Text2
```

The is not ok:

```
"Text1", "Text2" | Create-FileHTML -Path "L:\" -FileName "Title"
L:\ Title Text1 Text1
L:\ Title Text2 Text2
```

How is it possible to feed 2 values to the function to have the same result as my first example when using the pipeline?

The function:

```
Function Create-FileHTML {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
          [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})]
          [String[]] $Path,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
          [String[]] $FileName,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=3)]
          [String[]] $Message1,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=4)]
          [String[]] $Message2
        )
    Process {
         Write-Host "$Path $FileName $Message1 $Message2"
     }
}
```

Thank you for your help or tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ValueFromPipeline` to send more than one parameter, Use `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` rather like and send the parameters like:

```
$params = New-Object psobject -property @{Message1 = 'Text1'; Message2 = 'Text2'}  
$params | Create-FileHTML -Path "L:\" -FileName "Title"
```

Comment: Thank you Nadeem, didn't know this was possible.